# PayPal Create Order Service Error : PAYMENT_NOT_APPROVED_FOR_EXECUTION

Tags: paypal, cybersource

I am trying to create an order service in Paypal through CyberSource integration. I am always getting the following error.

```
PAYMENT_NOT_APPROVED_FOR_EXECUTION
```

I am using the following XML request to create order service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<requestMessage xmlns="urn:schemas-cybersource-com:transaction-data-1.162">
<merchantID>mid1235</merchantID>
<merchantReferenceCode>1234</merchantReferenceCode>

<purchaseTotals>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <grandTotalAmount>5.00</grandTotalAmount>
</purchaseTotals>
<apPaymentType>PPL</apPaymentType>
<ap>
    <payerID>************</payerID>
</ap>
<apOrderService run="true">
    <sessionsRequestID>6922833788036027603010</sessionsRequestID>
</apOrderService>
</requestMessage>
```

Comment: A payer needs to approve the payment. You cannot execute payments there is no payer for.

Comment: I am using my personal developer account as Payer Id. I don't see any notification

Comment: Orders need to be approved after creation. It is normal for orders to be created in an unapproved state and not yet be approved for execution, so perhaps you are complaining about a status that is not an error.